# Getting a certain row in Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase

This is the code I got of the Firebase documentation. It returns everything inside the table, so in this case

```
 Object { first: "Fred",  last: "Flintstone"}
```

But I only need it to return the value of `first`, which is `"Fred"`.

```js
var dbFirebase = new Firebase("firebaselink")

dbFirebase.once('value', function(nameSnapshot) {
  var val = nameSnapshot.val();
  console.log(val);
  // val now contains the object { first: 'Fred', last: 'Flintstone' }.
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.4/firebase.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, this should return the first object.

```
console.log("First Name: " + val.first);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Firebase, every property in your JSON tree has its own address. So if `firebaseLink` points to the entire `{ first: 'Fred', last: 'Flintstone' }` object, then `firebaseLink/first` will refer to just his first name.

As an alternative to Yuuin's solution, you can attach your callback to listen the `first` name:

```
var dbFirebase = new Firebase("firebaselink/first");

dbFirebase.once('value', function(nameSnapshot) {
  var val = nameSnapshot.val();
  console.log(val);
  // val now contains 'Fred'
});
```

Note that this is pretty well documented in [Firebase's guide on understanding its data structure](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/understanding-data.html).